# What's wrong with my nginx config when redirect to a different address based on the requested body content?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I want to redirect to a different address based on the requested body content.For example,if the body contains `<cityCode>100</cityCode>` or `<cityCode>110</cityCode>` ,then will jump to backend1.if the body contains `<cityCode>101</cityCode>` or `<cityCode>102</cityCode>` ,then will jump to backend2,otherwise it will jump to backend3.Now my request body has contains `<cityCode>101</cityCode>`,but it always jump to backend3.May I know where my configuration error is?

```
server {
listen 8080;
 client_max_body_size 200m;
location / {
#access_log /data/nginx/nginx/logs/request_body.log custom_log_format;
set $backend "backend3";
 if ($request_body ~* "<cityCode>100</cityCode>|<cityCode>110</cityCode>") {

    set $backend "backend1";
}
 if ($request_body ~* "<cityCode>101</cityCode>") { 
    set $backend "backend2";
}
proxy_pass http://$backend$request_uri;
}
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass_request_body on;
        proxy_set_header Content-Type  $http_content_type;
        proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
}
```